# TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API when splitting string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi all I have this code:

```
data = data.split('&')
```

And I get the following error:

> data = data.split('&') TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer
>   API

How to split my string?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`data`is a `bytes` object. You can only use another `bytes` value to split it, you can use a `bytes` literal (starting with the `b` prefix) to create one:

```
data.split(b'&')
```